# meteor send email by date and time

Tags: javascript, date, meteor, setinterval, momentjs

I think this is one of the hardest problems im dealing with in my app,
i have installed moment.js (using mrt).
and what i want to do is let the user pick a date and a time that the server will send an email to that user friends.
so for example: now is thursday 9:13 pm and the user want to send the message monday at 6:47 am.
and after the user have set the time i want the email to be sent repeatedly every week at the day and time that the user have set.
so i thought using moment.js like that (client side):

```
var now = moment(); (the current date and time).
```

then use a datepicker like jqueryui or a common one, and a timepicker,for setting the time and date that the user selected like that(client side):

```
var day = user selection using datepicker;
var time = user selection using timepicker;
var result = moment.set(day,time);
```

insert the result to the database:

```
DateToSendEmail.insert({date:result});
```

and finally have the code to really execute the Email.send function (on the server side):

```
var DateToSend = DateToSendEmail.findOne({});
var thisMoment = moment();
if(DateToSend === thisMoment){
Email.send({
to:[friends]
from:"myApplication@xxx.com"
Subject:"auto email send"
html:"auto email send"
});
}
```

the one thing that i don't know is whether it will work if the user isnt entering the the app for along time (lets say a month) or should i use Meteor.setInterval to execute this function repeatedly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do something very similar in our app:

1. Insert pending emails into an `Emails` collection with an `emailAt` date.
2. Use `setInterval` on the server to regularly poll for emails to send.

Your polling code may look something like:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (process.env.METEOR_ENV === 'production') {
    Meteor.setInterval(sendPendingEmails, ONE_HOUR);
  }
});
```

Fortunately, `Date` objects are written in UTC so any math you do on them should be independent of the timezone of either your users or your server. Furthermore, you can use `$lte` when fetching from the `Emails` collection like so:

```
var sendPendingEmails = function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var pendingEmails = Emails.find({emailAt: {$lte: currentDate}}).fetch();
  ...
};
```

It's important to remember that your server could be reset/hang/etc. so you'd want to set a polling interval small enough to compensate for this and to get close to the `emailAt` time without imposing too much load on your DB.

BTW if you run into any issues manipulating or comparing with moment objects you may want to call `toDate()` on them before they interact with the DB.

Comment: thanks, ill check it out and try playing around with it, ill be sure to tell you if i manged this issue and how.thank you agian David Weldon

Comment: Hey David i was wondering why did you choose to preform a $lte? considering you have hundreds of emails need to be sent why not getting only those who match today like that: var d = new Date();
    var d = d.getDay(); //need to be a number (0,1,2 ...)
    var pendingEmails = Groups.find({emailAt: d}).fetch(); that operation will make less load on the DB.

Comment: In our case, we remove items from the emails collection after they are sent, so `$lte` will always return the set that we want. In your implementation if you need to keep the emails around then you should add a filter to the query as you suggested.